# CRITICAL:root:Cannot load caffe2.python. Error: liblmdb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, caffe2

I installed caffe2 cpu pre-binary version in my ubuntu16.04，however when I import caffe2.python，it showed the following errors:

> CRITICAL:root:Cannot load caffe2.python. Error: liblmdb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[image]